# Learning Python the Hardway

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have opened and Powershell and when I type Python I get the message, `The term 'Python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, scriptfile, or operable program,` I did like the book said and typed in the `[Enviroment]::SetEnviromentVariable etc.` Still not working.

What do I try next. I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: use lowercase. python

Comment: What happen if you type: `c:\python27\python.exe` ?

Comment: Have you installed python yet?

Answer (score 0):

You have typed `Python`. You need a lower case: `python`.

(obviously, make sure you have it installed first, unlike mac os x, it does not come with most default installations).